# Pandas DF From and Back to MySQL

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pymysql

```
import config
import pandas as pd
import pymysql

username = config.username
dbpassword = config.dbpassword
dbhost = config.dburl
engine =  pymysql.connect(host=dbhost, port=3306,user=username,password=dbpassword,db='db',autocommit=True) 

tableBuilder1='''SELECT b.`IssueId` AS `Id`, b.`ShortId` AS `ShortId`, b.`Path` AS `Path`, b.`Data` AS `Data`,  b.`Actual Create Date` AS `Actual Create Date` FROM `SIM_FE_Audit_Data` b WHERE b.`Data` IN ( 'Open', 'Comment', 'Pending Others', 'Work in Progress', 'Resolved') AND NOT b.`IssueId` IN (SELECT c.`IssueId` FROM `SIM_FE_Audit_Data` c WHERE b.`Actual Create Date` = c.`Actual Create Date` AND b.`Data` = 'Comment' AND c.`Data` = 'Open') ORDER BY b.`IssueId`, b.`Actual Create Date`'''

df = pd.read_sql(tableBuilder1, con=engine)
df.to_sql('SIM_FE_Audit_Durations_No_First_Comment', con=engine, if_exists='replace',index=False)
```

The above code is being developed to replace views due to the views taking 15+ minutes to render and causing failures of tableau dashboards.  This first part is to make the first table in a series of 3.  However, I currently get an error `DatabaseError: Execution failed on sql 'SELECT name FROM sqlite_master WHERE type='table' AND name=?;': not all arguments converted during string formatting` on the df.to_sql and I cannot figure out why I am getting that error.  I did a print(df) to verify it is reading the sql and it is.  Writing it back to the new table is generating the error and I don't understand why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

swapping to sqlalchemy directly seems to have fixed it:

```
import config
import pandas as pd
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
import time

username = config.username
dbpassword = config.dbpassword
dbhost = config.dburl
engine =  create_engine('mysql://%s:%s@%s/db?charset=utf8' %(username, dbpassword, dbhost), encoding="utf-8") 

tableBuilder1='''SELECT b.`IssueId` AS `Id`, b.`ShortId` AS `ShortId`, b.`Path` AS `Path`, b.`Data` AS `Data`,  b.`Actual Create Date` AS `Actual Create Date` FROM `SIM_FE_Audit_Data` b WHERE b.`Data` IN ( 'Open', 'Comment', 'Pending Others', 'Work in Progress', 'Resolved') AND NOT b.`IssueId` IN (SELECT c.`IssueId` FROM `SIM_FE_Audit_Data` c WHERE b.`Actual Create Date` = c.`Actual Create Date` AND b.`Data` = 'Comment' AND c.`Data` = 'Open') ORDER BY b.`IssueId`, b.`Actual Create Date`'''

df = pd.read_sql(tableBuilder1, con=engine)
df.to_sql('SIM_FE_Audit_Durations_No_First_Comment', con=engine, if_exists='replace')
```